# NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy triggers guardMalloc when released

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, wsdl, base64

Please see update below

```
<s:element name="GetFile">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ObjectId" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetFileResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <!-- This is the return value -->
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" 
       name="GetFileResult" type="s:base64Binary"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

With the generated code from wsdl2objc I get an error with guard malloc enabled:

> GuardMalloc[eBridge-1115]: guard
>   malloc zone failure: freeing a pointer
>   we didn't allocate that was not
>   claimed by any registered zone
>   GuardMalloc[eBridge-1115]: Explicitly
>   trapping into debugger!!!

This is the last obj-c code i can see before it goes all asm on me:

```
@implementation WebServices_GetFileResponse
- (void)dealloc
{
    [soapSigner release];
    //breaks on the line below
    if(GetFileResult != nil) [GetFileResult release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I believe it is breaking in the generated Response object's **deserializeElementsFromNode** but have not pinpointed it yet. This is not a "Debug my program for me" question. My question is simply - Has anyone ran into this problem with a base64Binary byte array return type generated by wsdl2objc?

**Update**

---

The problem I believe lies in

```
+ (id)dateWithBase64EncodedString;
```

in NSData (MBBase64) -

```
char *data = malloc(...);
NSUInteger length = 0;

... // fill data[length++];

realloc(data, length);
return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:length]; //offending line?
```

Im making an assumption that this does not make the objective-c runtime claim the memory.. so when I am releasing the NSData it is somehow still allocated with 'malloc'. Does anyone know better than I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In + (id)dateWithBase64EncodedString I changed the last line to:

```
return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:length **freeWhenDone:NO**];
```

and it seemed to work. This is just my hack, but if you are the author of wsdl2objc sees this hopefully it will help.